# Is there a maximum limit to number of tweets that you can fetch using tweepy python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

Is there a maximum limit to number of tweets that you can fetch using tweepy python?

Comment: do you mean per minute?

Comment: The twitter api itself has some strict restrictions based on the "tier" of api access you have. The specifications should be looked up on their site. Tweepy is essentially just a wrapper accessing the twitter api.

Comment: I'm doing some sentiment analysis on various hashtag and require data hourly, by day and by week. It's taking forever for some popular hashtags, so i was just curious, how can i overcome this? I am using standard twitter developer account and fetching tweets by doing      tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=hashtag,lang="en",since=last_week_str).items()

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you are a regular developer, the maximum is 3,200.

> This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user's most recent Tweets.
>   https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html

Comment: I'm doing some sentiment analysis on various hashtag and require data hourly, by day and by week. It's taking forever for some popular hashtags, so i was just curious, how can i overcome this? I am using standard twitter developer account and fetching tweets by doing tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=hashtag,lang="en",since=last_week_str).items()

Comment: Take a look at the streaming API. Or pay Twitter for premium API access. That's pretty much all you can do.